# Making a mutable array from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to make an `NSArray` from a key in save data and make it mutable. Here's what I have so far:

```
NSMutableArray *availableThemes = [[[saveData valueForKey:@"availableThemes"] array] mutableCopy];
```

If I'm correct, sending `array` makes this object returned by `availableThemes` an array with the contents of the object, and then `mutableCopy` makes this array a `NSMutableArray`. Sadly, and obviously, I'm not. I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray array]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x786c7430'
```

Here, I thought, sending `array` would turn this data into a `NSArray`. Instead, it causes a complier error. I know I did something stupidly wrong. Question is, what did I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the class method `array` on an instance of `NSArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *availableThemes = [[[saveData valueForKey:@"availableThemes"] array] mutableCopy];
```

From your crash log it is clear that the `availableThemes` key returns an `NSArray` object, so change your code to:

```
NSMutableArray *availableThemes = [[saveData valueForKey:@"availableThemes"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: This code works! I thought `valueForKey` returned `id`, which, I thought meant `unspecified object type` or `NSObject`.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE: Yes, it returns an id object (It can be anything, in your case it is an `NSArray`)